# Windows 7: Create Restore Point timeout

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

Restore Point creation fails with error 0x81000101 (timeout).
Command "vssadmin List Writers" shows timeout results for:

```
Writer name: 'Shadow Copy Optimization Writer'
   Writer Id: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
   Writer Instance Id: {dbfd075a-7b57-4a02-aead-991d369ee973}
   State: [9] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'COM+ REGDB Writer'
   Writer Id: {542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}
   Writer Instance Id: {b338b1a4-cb55-4e31-9864-44a0cac94863}
   State: [9] Failed
   Last error: Timed out
```

Other writers work well.
Restart VSS service didn't help.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: Those are all working here. The two you said did not work are my last two. I listed 10 in total.  (1) do you have more than 10 and (2) try running System File checker and then restart (SFC /SCANNOW )

Comment: SFC reported errors at folder SystemRoot\WinSxS\Temp\PendingRenames\ but I can’t delete files in this folder even in Windows Safe Mode.

Comment: That folder is empty on my machine. You may consider deleting the files with Unlocker 1.9.2 (Softpedia or Major Geeks)

Comment: New program installations require to create restore point - which doesn't work.

Comment: You could look at the folders for old content that is no longer needed. I have installed software on that Windows 7 machine not too long ago and the entire folder is empty

Comment: Maybe it's Windows updates that didn't install successfully.

Comment: That is certainly possible.  Also.  Restart and run SFC again. Sometimes the second try corrects errors

Comment: I tried this many times, the SFC cannot fix these errors automatically. Also, I can't fix this manually.

Comment: See this>>>>>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/0x81000101-shadow-copy-timeout-error/6232100d-1b9b-46ed-960d-f5a866e357c5

Comment: I would try deleting the contents of the Pending Renames folders (no folders - just files).  I ran this command on my very active Windows 10 machine and Pending Renames is empty there. There are two other non-empty folders but VSSADMIN does not deal with these.

Comment: Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 48 KB (0%)
Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 640 MB (0%)
Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 1.5 GB (1%)
---
More than 48KB is not recorded and timeouts again.

Comment: DiskCleanUp also can't delete files from PendingRenames folder.

Comment: You may wish to consider a Windows 7 repair install. See this Seven Forums link below.   Use care and read the entire article before starting 

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: Windows 7 repair install only overwrite existing system files - this will not help.

Comment: If you truly need to solve the issue, back up the machine and reinstall Windows. That is truly the answer when "Nothing works"

Comment: No. It's a very bad solution.

Comment: Then you will just have to live with the issue. Nothing else has worked and Windows 7 has died, so time anyway to move along.

Comment: The problem is related to corruption with the last windows update. Need try to clean these corrupted files from PendingRenames folder. Windows cannot automatically complete the installation of the last windows update on reboot.

Comment: For what it may be worth, there was an update in my Windows 7 system today 4/26 for Generic Volume Shadow Copy. See if updating your Widows 7 helps in any way

Comment: I managed to do In Safe Mode stop most services and clean corrupted files and remove Windows Update folder, but now Windows could not search for new updates with error code: 80080005